# Convert a colour to a darker shade in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a colour picker that allows my Xamarin app to set a theme colour. I want to calculate a darker shade of the same colour to identify different items.

How can I calculate a darker shade from a colour?

Comment: My idea would be have a look how RGB are working on out colours(i would assume that darker the color, higher the value) and write an algorithm from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Assuming* this is a Forms' Color, you can use the `WithLuminosity` method to decrease its "brightness" value and return a new darker color.

Example:

```
var color = label.BackgroundColor;
var newColor = color.WithLuminosity(color.Luminosity - (color.Luminosity * .1));
label.BackgroundColor = newColor;
```

Comment: Why not `color.Luminosity * 0.9`?

Comment: @Knoop LOL... I cut/pasted/edited from actual code that is doing a luminosity cascade in a animation function across *multiple* controls so the `lum * .1` was from a different color, but yea, in this case .9 would work just fine

Comment: Haha no worries, saw that code and was wondering "hmm, am I missing something…?"^^