# C# Xamarin Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms

Code

```
<Shell.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush.... 
</Shell.Background>
```

don't work.
But code

```
<Shell.... 
BackgroundColor="#00FFBB">
```

Is working, but color is darker than real "#00FFBB". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I can replicate the issue on my side and there's an open issue about `Shell.Background not displaying gradient Brush` on Github.

You can follow it up here:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13066.

Comment: Ok, but how to do real 00FFBB, not darker?

Comment: You can use #00FFD0 as an alternative choice.

Answer (score 0):

I firstly suggest reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182688/xamarin-shell-backgroundcolor-is-wrong?rq=1), if this doesn't correct your problem you could play with color luminosity (or brightness) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863277/convert-a-colour-to-a-darker-shade-in-xamarin); to modify your Shell color brightness I suggest you change it using code

Example:

```
var colorMain = Color.FromHex("#00FFBB"); //Your color
colorMain = colorMain.WithLuminosity((float)(colorMain.GetLuminosity() * 1.1)); //Make it brighter

Shell.SetBackgroundColor(Shell.Current, colorMain); //Setting brighter color to the Shell
```

Comment: Its not working :(

Comment: Neither of them? You have this problem on iOS or Android?

Comment: In your question the solution on Ios, but I'm developing program on android

Comment: Okay, this i think will work with iOS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783581/xamarin-forms-4-0-shell-titleview-ios-cannot-set-black-background-color?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: But i need for solution on android